# Choosing between side effects and good API design in functional programming with scala

Tags: oop, scala, functional-programming

I'm porting to scala a java application I wrote as a learning exercise. Part of it is communicating with another machine using a protocol directly over TCP. This protocol has 2 layers (Application and Transport) with corresponding headers and trailers. So a given message would end looking like

> tHeader | aHeader | message | aTrailer | tTrailer

I thought of using a

```
trait Layer{
   def write(s:String) : Unit
   def read :String
}
```

Each layer would complete the message with its header|trailer and pass it to the next layer. I would then have a `TransportLayer` and a `ApplicationLayer` which I could combine in an implementation like

```
 val layer = new TcpLayer with ApplicationLayer with TransportLayer
```

I was thrilled with this design, it allowed me to reuse the components  at will. And then my dilemma appeared:

- In order to avoid side effects, the `write` method should not return `Unit`,but the modified `String`, which should then be sent. This minimizes the side effects, eases testing, but the client code would need to send the completed `String` over the socket itself ( which already has a side effect but no way around that one, or?).
- Since the client code should 'fire and forget', it should be able to call `write` on a given `Layer` and don't care about the modified `String` ( which might be gibberish to him anyway) . Therefore I think to return `Unit` is the correct choice for the return value.

Any thoughtful insights on which version is more functional programming - friendly?

Answer (score 1):

If the only side-effect is in the socket, then how about this:

```
val layers = new TcpLayer with ApplicationLayer with TransportLayer
socket.write (layers.write (message))
unitTestEngine.check (layers.write (message))
```

Or if the client only have the `layer` to work with, then:

```
val layers = new TcpLayer (socket) with ApplicationLayer with TransportLayer
layers.sink (layers.write (message))
unitTestEngine.check (layers.write (message))
```

Where `sink` is a method returning the Socket instance.